# java network event listener

Tags: java, networking

Now, I want to implement an event listener to make network request to async like Object-c or Js.
I wanna to got the HeaderReceived evnent, How much bytes downloaded(means progress),got response event.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client). It's a good framework written by Jean-François Arcand (which has largely contributed to the Glassfish Application Server by writing large parts of the Grizzly web server)

Comment: I want to know, How do you know headerReceived?use getResponseHeader()?

Comment: check the README of the library, there's a `onHeadersReceived` callback

Comment: not yet, I think, if we believe [this recent thread on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/asynchttpclient/CGvcPyJaO-k)